# How to implement MVC pattern in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, polymer-starter-kit

Can we define controller for polymer element? For example, I have a ListView as element.Now I want to implement onClickEvent() in controller to keep business / other logic separate from View. So is there any View-Controller binding available in polymer.?

Comment: Let me understand better: what you want avoid is to use the on-click binding on the element?

Comment: No I want to implement onClick event but Implementation should go to Controller class... View should just have declaration.(method name ) and defination and llogic of onClickEvent should go into Controller. So My question is there any way to implement MVC where we can keep Controller for every Custom Element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic structure of a Polymer element embeds the MVC solution for you, doesn't it?

For example, the general structure is:

```
<dom-module id="my-module">
  <!-- Imports go here -->
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/example-imported-element/example-imported-element.html">
  <style>
    ...
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-button on-click="myFunc"></paper-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
        Polymer({
          is: "my-module",
          ...
          myFunc: function() {
            // Do stuff
          },
          ...
        });
      }()
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

So your "model" is your [Shadow DOM](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/), everything inside your `<template>` tags are your "views" and everything inside your `Polymer()` function is your "controller" isn't it? (Even thought it's not formally labeled that way.) Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Thanks Mowzer for detail explanation. You made one of my doubt clear. But what I was also thinking to move <script> (function() {
    Polymer({..... </script> part to separate .js file which will have myFunc: function(){
        // Do stuff
      },

Comment: That would work. But it would be unusual because the whole idea of Polymer elements is to make reusable blocks of code that can be easily moved around, inserted and deleted from your apps with one imported file into your `bower_components` directory, then into your app with a `<link>` tag such as `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">`. By creating a separate `.js` file, you will create the need to do two `bower` imports if you want to make your custom element reusable by your other apps.